# Spring batch job scope issue on parallel runs of job instances

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring batch 4 and have a job definition with 4 steps each containing a tasklet. There are few job scope beans defined. My understanding is that job scoped bean is unique for a job instance. The job is invoked using the job parameter that is unique for every run.

Now the problem is the job scope beans created in one job instance is getting into another job instance. Scenario is the first tasklet creates a bean that is of job scope and this is accessed in another tasklet. When multiple job instances are invoked, when the step2 tasklet of job instance-2 access the job scoped bean it is getting injected with bean that is created by job instance-1. Ideally the bean created in job instance-2 should have been passed.

**Job definition:**

```
<batch:job id="batchJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="step2"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <tasklet ref="tasklet2" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="step3"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step3">
        <tasklet ref="tasklet3" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="step4"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step4">
        <tasklet ref="tasklet4" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

**job scoped bean definition:**

```
<bean id="testVo" class="com.test.model.report.TestVo" scope="job"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope" />
```

**Job Launching through the job parameter:**

```
JobParameters jobParameters = 
              new JobParametersBuilder()
              .addLong("jobStartTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
              .addLong("requestId", Long.valueOf(payload)).toJobParameters();

jobLauncher.run(batchJob, jobParameters);
```

Sample Tasklet definition and its access for job scoped bean

```
@Component
public class Tasklet2 implements Tasklet {

  /** The job scoped bean. */
  @Autowired
  private TestVo testVo;

  ....
}
```

Is there any specific issue in the above configuration. Why is the job scoped bean gets mixed across job instances?

Comment: If your tasklet is creating the class instance, it's not job scoped.  Spring beans have those types of scopes.  We'd have to see the definition of the bean in question and how it's used to understand what's going on...

Comment: I have updated the question to include how the job scope bean is defined and how its been injected into the tasklet